# Spacetimes where symmetries vary from place to place?

Tags: general-relativity, space-time, space, space-geometry, theories

Are there spacetimes or metrics where symmetries (like Poincaré, Lorentz, diffeomorphism, translational... invariances) are only local and the symmetries of one local neighbourhood are not, a priori, the same for another, even close to it? I mean spacetimes with "local neighbourhoods" which are not diffeomorphic to each other in some way?